# Is there an general formula for turning iterative solutions into recursive ones?

Tags: java, recursion

I have been struggling on labs that require me to turn my iterative solutions into recursive ones.

I really struggle with recursion and I get the idea of it, but I feel that there has to be a better way than so much trial and error.

I am not a super advanced programmer so I am not too good, but I am curious if there is a mold that can fit most of the time.

Any feedback appreciated. I know Java best so if it is in terms of Java it would really help!

Comment: Why exactly to you want to use recursion instead of iteration? I'm asking because it might be a really bad idea. Can you give us some example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally iterative solutions can be reduced to the format:

```
function iterative(information): 
    while (condition) do
        modify information
    end while
    return some value
end function
```

This can be changed to a recursive function by rearranging the code so the format is:

```
function recursive(information):
    if(condition) then
        modify information
        recursive(information)
    else
        return some value
    end if
end function
```

Keep in mind this is a VERY general formula, and you are still going to need to do a lot of work on some (most) problems.

**Final Note:** iterative solutions are often the best way to go. Using recursion is worse on memory and generally worse on performance. It is almost exclusively used to make something easier to read, understand, or implement (A Depth First Search is a very good example of this, look into the iterative and recursive algorithms for it). Try to keep this in mind while learning these things in school, just because you are being taught one thing does not mean that it is the best way to go, make sure to do additional research and test things for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I dislike the idea of labs that have you turn iterative solutions into recursive ones. If there is an iterative solution, it is usually better to just use it.

However, if the iterative solution has you saving a lot of state between iterations -- a LOT of state -- then perhaps that's better done with recursion.

I don't know that there is any "general formula" for doing this. I think about the possibility of recursion when faced with a problem which can be divided into smaller identical problems.

Consider doing something to all the files on a hard drive. You can do this iteratively, but it's hard to picture all the state you have to save, and if you want to do something to each of the folders as well, it could get unwieldy. The recursive solution is "z: for each file, do x, for each folder, do y and z (or z and y)".

Contrast this with factorials -- you can do factorials with recursion, but the iterative solution is so simple, I hate to see it even used as an example. I suppose, though, conceptually, it is another case of a problem that is made up of smaller identical problems.

Don't know if that's any help, but that's how I think of it.

Comment: Thanks for the tips it helps yeah. I agree that the iterative is almost always better, but when its required you gotta do what you gotta do....  Also I hope this isn't crazy but I really want to start getting more involved in the community and helping answer questions that I see and know I can help.  Any tips for getting rep points.  I don't see questions getting up voted much so I can never get to the point of helping people.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should only use recursion if there is a problem to which you can apply a certain set of operations that make the problem functionally the same, but smaller.

Take counting the files on your harddrive, you could do it iteratively, but it's pretty cumbersome. But it is a problem that you can apply a set of operations to that make the problem functionally the same, but smaller: You can count the files of only the current directory and add the counts of the subdirectory.

So in general, if you can describe your problem in terms like this:

```
function fixTheProblem(thingToFix) {
    if (problemCanBeFixedDirectly) // IE no more subdirectories
        return calculateProblemResult(); // IE Count files in current directory
    else {
        var result = calculateSmallSubProblem(); // IE count files in current
        var smallerButSimilarProblems = breakupProblem(); // IE take subdirecties
        foreach (var smallerProblem in smallerButSimilarProblems) {
            var intermediateResult = fixTheProblem(smallerProblem);
            result += intermediateResult;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```